# gdb 7.0, signal SIGCONT doesn't break from a pause() call

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I'd built a version of gdb 7.0 for myself after being pointed to a new feature, and happened to have that in my path still.

Attempting to step through some new code, I'd added a pause() call, expecting to be able to get out like so:

```
(gdb) b 5048
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2b1811b25052: file testca.C, line 5048.
(gdb) signal SIGCONT
Continuing with signal SIGCONT.

Breakpoint 1, FLUSH_SUDF_TEST (h=@0x2b1811b061c0) at testca.C:5048
5048       rc = h.SAL_testcaFlushPagesByUDF( uPrimary - 1, uPrimary ) ;
```

(that was with the system gdb, version 6.6).

With gdb 7.0 I never hit the post-pause() breakpoint when I try this.  With the various multi process debugging changes in gdb 7, does anybody know if signal handling has to be handled differently and how?

Comment: I have never seen the use of 'signal SIGCONT' to continue from a breakpoint. Usually one uses 'continue'. Did you try that?

Comment: The breakpoint was set after the pause() syscall, and the intention is to get _to_ that point (you can try this on gdb 6.6 for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pause()` function does not return unless a signal handler is called (see the [specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pause.html) and the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pause)).

To make it return after your program receives SIGCONT, you must install an handler for SIGCONT. Try and see using the following example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile int caught_signal = 0;

void handler(int sig)
{
    caught_signal = sig; 
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGCONT, handler);
    pause();
    printf("Caught signal: %d, %s\n",
            caught_signal, strsignal(caught_signal));
    return 0;
}
```

The behavior is correct with gdb 7.0: `pause()` completely ignores ignored signals (like `SIGCHLD`, returns on caught signals (`SIGCONT`), and no signal is delivered when the `continue` command is issued.

```
(gdb) break 17
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484b3: file pause.c, line 17.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) signal SIGCHLD
Continuing with signal SIGCHLD.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) signal SIGCONT
Continuing with signal SIGCONT.

Breakpoint 1, main () at pause.c:17
17      printf("Caught signal: %d, %s\n",
(gdb)
```

Comment: Ah.  Excellent.  Thank you very much.  I'm able to use SIGPROF which we have hijacked for a handler that has no significant side effects.